# How can I pip freeze and get only pip --user installs, no system installs?

Tags: python, pip

I have dutifully uninstalled all the Python packages I installed with `sudo pip install` and installed them with `pip --user install` instead. Yay me :)

On Ubuntu, I know I can find the relevant binaries at `/home/<USERNAME>/.local/bin` and the packages themselves at `/home/<USERNAME>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` ... but navigating there is not as simple as good old `pip freeze`.

How can I `pip freeze` and get only the packages I installed with `pip --user install` rather than all the Python packages, including those installed via apt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently `pip` does not have any such options. So with default pip its not possible. (and I submitted a feature [request](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2092) and now there is a working [PR](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/2093) too!)

However I wrote a little script, which does solve your problem:

```
# pip_user_installs.py
import sys
import pkg_resources
for module in pkg_resources.working_set:
    if sys.argv[1] in module.location:
        print module.project_name
```

usage:

```
$ python pip_user_installs.py $HOME
```

Comment: Maybe it makes more sense to include `$HOME` in the script?

Comment: if you want to check other user installs then you can just do `python pip_user_installs.py /home/someguy`

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly easy in recent versions of pip (the PR in the other answer is now part of pip).

`pip freeze --user`

This will output a list of packages currently installed to the user's site-packages.